# Split comma-separated column data into multiple columns (Variable size)

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, split

Need some help splitting column data (string) in `Postgres` into multiple dummy columns such as:

```
---------column-------
data1;data2;data3 -
data1;data3       -
data1             -
```

into

```
- Col1 ---- Col2 ---- Col3
   1    |    1    |   1
   1    |    0    |   1
   1    |    0    |   0
```

I know the maximum number of columns so I can preset the dummy columns. Do I need to do some sort of for loop?

JP

Answer (score 3):

You can either use split_part():

```
select split_part(col, ';', 1) as col1, 
       split_part(col, ';', 2) as col2, 
       split_part(col, ';', 3) as col1
from the_table;
```

Or slightly more efficient because the splitting is only done once per row:

```
select c[1] as col1, 
       c[2] as col2, 
       c[3] as col3
from (
  select string_to_array(col, ';') as c
  from the_table
) t;
```